# IOS - trigger a SMS message as an alarm (send a single userpredifined SMS message automatically)

Tags: iphone, ios, automation, sms, alarm

I am programming a location triggered alarm, for wich the user can be informed either by ringtone or SMS.

For the SMS: the users defines the SMS content and contact, when the alarm is triggered i want to send it once. The alarm is then disabled.

The ringtone is quite easy, however other posts emphasize that it is not possible to send the SMS automatically or to delay the sending of a SMS.

However, that's what the Auto Alert Alarm Clock available on the app store is doing:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/auto-alert-alarm-clock/id639611413?mt=8

any hint on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They most likely have their own server that the app sends a request to. When the server receives the request, it sends a text message to the designated number.

Comment: That would not work for me, as the whole point if SMS is to have a cheap distant alert while abroad. A SMS alerts allows to turn off roaming whereas a server would require to turn on data.

Comment: @user2448569 yeah...I thought of that after I wrote this answer...

Why don't you try looking for a 3rd party framework for doing this?

Comment: thanks for the tip, all i have found yet is for Jailbroken Iphones , but i'll keep searching ^^